# SWIG and C#: insert empty C# class

Tags: c#, c++, swig

Is there a way (typemap or pragma) to insert custom C# class into generated C# code? It's easy to add code to wrapped C++ classes with `%typemap(cscode)` - but not clear for adding C# classes...

For example, SWIG [doc](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_custom_application_exception) for creating custom exceptions says:

The boiler plate code above must be used in addition to a handcrafted `CustomApplicationException`:

```
// Custom C# Exception
public class CustomApplicationException : global::System.ApplicationException {
  public CustomApplicationException(string message) 
    : base(message) {
  }
}
```

But it's not clear how to add this class through interface file.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for... Clearly you can do `class My.Awesome.Random.Namespace.Here.CustomApplicationException...` or `class System.CustomApplicationException` but you are likely looking for something else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - yes, obviously, I can insert this class right into C# code with no problems within any namespace... My question is how to insert this C# class using SWIG _interface_ file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a documented pragma that gets close to what you want,  [`%pragma(csharp) imclasscode`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html#csharp_custom_application_exception). This inserts code into the modulePINVOKE.cs file that gets generated.

In the source tree for SWIG though we find:

> ```
>   /* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    * pragmaDirective()
>    *
>    * Valid Pragmas:
>    * imclassbase            - base (extends) for the intermediary class
>    * imclassclassmodifiers  - class modifiers for the intermediary class
>    * imclasscode            - text (C# code) is copied verbatim to the intermediary class
>    * imclassimports         - import statements for the intermediary class
>    * imclassinterfaces      - interface (implements) for the intermediary class
>    *
>    * modulebase              - base (extends) for the module class
>    * moduleclassmodifiers    - class modifiers for the module class
>    * modulecode              - text (C# code) is copied verbatim to the module class
>    * moduleimports           - import statements for the module class
>    * moduleinterfaces        - interface (implements) for the module class
>    *
>    * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
>
>   virtual int pragmaDirective(Node *n) {
> ```

So, assuming you're happy with a nested class the following:

```
%module test

%pragma(csharp) modulecode=%{
// Custom C# Exception
public class CustomApplicationException : global::System.ApplicationException {
  public CustomApplicationException(string message)
    : base(message) {
  }
}
%}
```

does exactly what you wanted inside of module.cs. If that isn't sufficient then we'd have to start looking at workarounds and it probably becomes cleaner and simpler to just write the small independent chunk of code outside of SWIG by hand (but in the same source tree).

---

If you really want to go into the realm of workarounds you can (ab)use the moduleclassmodifiers pragma to insert things into the global namespace, for example:

```
%module test

%pragma(csharp) moduleclassmodifiers=%{
// Custom C# Exception
public class CustomApplicationException : global::System.ApplicationException {
  public CustomApplicationException(string message)
    : base(message) {
  }
}

public class%}
```

Produces test.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


// Custom C# Exception
public class CustomApplicationException : global::System.ApplicationException {
  public CustomApplicationException(string message)
    : base(message) {
  }
}

public class test {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Flexo. I've actually tried this before - both `modulecode` and `imclasscode` pragmas would insert C# code into other classes, not into global namespace or new file...

Comment: I found a simple solution, which preserves automatism, but unfortunately outside of SWIG -- create the `.cs` file with needed C# code in Wrapper project and copy it on the post-build event near the files that SWIG generates. Pretty stupid but does the job...

Comment: @OlegShirokikh I added a workaround that would do more like what you're looking for then

Comment: Flexo - wow :) that's an awesome hack! I understand that whole this issue is very minor but it's always fun to explore even such small details of SWIG. Thanks for awesome work!

Comment: 5 years later, and this hack is the only way I can find to insert raw C# code that doesn't live in some SWIG-generated class.